# Keras Upsampling2d -> tflite conversion results in failing shape inference and undefined output shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

Keras Upsampling2d operation is converted into this with additional operations and undefined shape

[image]

Tensorflow however converts without this operations with correct shape

[image]

This leads to undefined overall model output shape and leads to errors on device. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is described here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45090

> Keras by default sets dynamic batch size to true.
> That means that the model input shape is [*,28,28] not [1,28,28].
> The old(deprecated) converter used to ignore the dynamic batch and override this to 1 - which is wrong since this is not what the original model has - you can imagine how bad it will be when you try to resize the inputs at runtime.

> The current converter instead handles the dynamic batch size correct, and the model generated can be resized at runtime correct.
> That's why the sequence of "Shape, StridedSlice, Pack" wasn't constant folded, since the shape is dependent on the shape defined at runtime.

For single input model this can be fixed by setting constant shape for keras model before saving

```
model.input.set_shape(1 + model.input.shape[1:])
```